# Выбор предлога: "по" или "обо"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Какой предлог употреблять: *грустить **по** мне* или *грустить **обо** мне?*

Answer (score 2):

И так и так можно. Смотрите на [Грамоте](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x):

**ГРУСТИТЬ,** грущу, грустишь; **нсв.** *о ком, о чём и по кому, чему.* **1.** Испытывать чувство грусти; печалиться. *Отчего грустите? Г. **о** былом. Г. **о** родных, **об** утраченных ценностях. Г. **по** семье, **по** дому. Г. без концертов, без работы. Г. день и ночь. Г. втайне.*

---

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса:**

Впрочем, я должен сознаться, что я не слишком долго *грустил **по** ней;* я даже нашёл, что судьба хорошо распорядилась, не соединив меня с Асей; я утешался мыслию, что я, вероятно, не был бы счастлив с такой женой. *[И. С. Тургенев. Ася (1858)]*

Героическая мать умирала от неизлечимой болезни и не желала, чтобы девочка потом *грустила **по** ней.* *[В. В. Набоков. Лолита [автоперевод с английского] (1967)]*

Вот письма родных, которые где-то там, на севере, все еще ждут меня к праздникам и *грустят **обо** мне* с нежною любовью, как о мальчике... [И. А. Бунин. Без роду-племени (1897)]*

Ты ждешь, Лизавета, от друга привета
И не спишь до рассвета, все *грустишь **обо** мне,*
Одержим победу, к тебе я приеду
На горячем боевом коне...
*[Г. Я. Бакланов. Навеки девятнадцатилетние (1979)]*

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, выбор может зависеть от *контекста*, это вопрос единства стиля. Вариант с "по" самодостаточен и имеет чисто "указательный" оттенок: кто на кого направляет свою грусть, сокрушается по поводу отсутствия другого и т. п. Вариант с "о" соответствует более "содержательному" контексту: это может быть намёк на разнообразные воспоминания "о" предмете грусти, которые ясны из предшествующего повествования или раскрываются вскоре после упоминания о факте грусти.